# What is the max USB cable type-A male to type-c male Volt/current/Wattage possible?

Tags: usb, power-supply, power, cable, usb-c

I am struggling to understand USB type-C specifications in terms of power supply,

It took me a lot to figure out about USB data bandwidth but now that type-C is used to charge mobiles I need to learn more.

Question seems simple to me, hope so. I need a fast charging USB adapter and looking online I found out one that says super-speed and has a detachable USB type-A male to type-C male cable, nobody lists the tech specs clearly, but as far as I understand a type-C to type-C cable could carry a lot of power, while a cable type-A male to type-C male could do less. So what is the max Volt/current/Wattage of USB cable type-A male to type-C male?

This is a picture of what I call a USB cable type-A male to type-C male, just to be sure I am getting it right.

[image]

Edited the question adding the power source adapter that is sold together with the cable, it has a USB type-A female plug, it says it is outputting both 5V, 9V, 12V

[image]

Comment: I would assume that the presence of the USB-C connector guarantees the full USB-C specification fully. But I haven't studied this in detail. You might better read which version of USB3 (at the power source) you have, and see if you can find a matching cable.

Comment: How much power will depend on which USB standard you are talking about.  Type-C is a the type of connector the USB port is configured to support.  It does not indicate which version of the standard you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as solved on https://electronics.stackexchange.com

by https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/241749/macguffin

here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/628801/what-is-the-maximum-usb-cable-type-a-male-to-type-c-male-voltage-current-power-p

I am copying it:

> They say it can deliver 5 V, 9 V, or 12V and I was trying to figure out how it would fit the USB standards, given that everybody everywhere says that USB 3.1 can output max 7,5 W (5 V at 1,5 A I believe). The adapter/charger carries an USB type-A female plug instead of a type-C which they told me could carry more power.

The short and simple answer is that they don't follow the USB standards.

The longer answer is that entities outside of the USB Implementers Forum (or USB-IF) wrote what might be described as "extensions" the USB standards that put more voltage and/or current into the USB-A connector than the USB-IF allow.

There's more than one of these extensions to the USB spec on power transfer, and not all of them are compatible with each other.  Some require non-standard cables to connect a USB-A power brick to a USB-C device to charge at the higher power levels.

That gets back to the earlier question:

> So what is the maximum voltage/current/power of a USB type-A male to type-C male cable?

The answer is it depends on which standard the cable follows.

The USB-IF has bumped up the maximum allowed current on USB-A over time and last I checked it allows a maximum of 2.4 amps.  The voltage allowed on USB-A is 5 volts, at least according to USB-IF.  There was the USB-PD 1.0 spec that allowed higher voltages on USB-A but I have not seen anyone actually use that spec in any devices available to the public.  It appears the USB-IF decided that USB-PD 1.0 was a bad idea and will not even test if devices comply with that spec.  USB-PD 2.0 replaced it, which was updated with USB-PD 3.0 and then again with USB-PD 3.1.  USB-PD 2.0 and up defines power transfer for USB-C, leaving USB-A at 5 volts and 2.4 amps as defined in other specifications.

These specifications created outside the USB-IF are so numerous, and go by different names depending on who is selling it, that it is difficult to say where the maximums on voltage and current lie.  Technically any connector that is rated for more than 5 volts and 2.4 amps is not a USB-A connector even if it looks like one.  If you ask what is the maximum voltage and current allowed by the USB spec on a USB-A to USB-C cable then the answer is 5 volts and 2.4 amps.  If the question is how much is allowed under standards outside what the USB-IF wrote then it's something like 20 volts and 5 amps.

How can these cables handle this much power if the USB-IF considers this much power unsafe?  One "trick" I saw was using all four pins in the USB-A connector for power.  This clearly violates the USB spec and renders the cable unusable for USB data transfer.  To make this work the device being charged has to use some circuitry that is outside what USB-IF defined, or the cable has circuitry outside what USB-IF defined.

There's a long history on why these "high power" USB-A power bricks became popular, which I won't go into because of length.  They are still popular today out of inertia, once they caught on it became difficult to be rid of them.

Comment: I wonder why no one mentioned to you that there's a BIG QuickCharge 3.0 logo on the photo you attached.

Comment: because no one noticed, maybe its not in the usb spec, feel free to edit the accepted answer. And now I am wonderibg why You didnt mention Qualcomm

Comment: By the way, AFAIK, there's no special requirement on the plug or wire for a cable to support higher voltage. But you do need "better" cable for larger current.

Comment: Anyway, the charger can deliver up to 18W, the bigger one gives 25W but uses a type-C  male to type-C male cable.

Answer (score 2):

> I am struggling to understand USB type-C specifications in terms of
> power supply,

This is a Qualcomm Quick Charge charger, spec 3. Functionality of QC is proprietary, and has nothing to do with USB Type-C specifications. And therefore any question about current/voltage/power across USB cable is misplaced. And mentioning "super speed" in adapter description is total misnomer, crude marketing BS. More, USB-C specifications explicitly forbid using any proprietary charging schema, so this charger does not fit into USB framework at all.

Comment: The port on a charger is an A though, but indeed most if not all proprietary protocol seems to do it like A to C (since micro-B is hardly used anymore for new devices) but not C to C.

Answer (score -3):

**Cable max: 3A@20V = 60W**

Club3D has a 60W Cable since 2016:
https://www.club-3d.com/en/detail/2354/usb_3.1_type_c_to_type_a_cable_10gbps_pd_60w_m-m_1m-3.28ft/

You can buy it at several places:
https://geizhals.eu/club-3d-usb-3-1-kabel-a1480441.html

**USB-A-Chargers:**

- [60W via USB-A (100W via USB-C)](https://geizhals.eu/baseus-usb-c-ladegeraet-pd-100w-schwarz-a2758433.html)
- [60W via USB-A (65W via USB-C)](https://geizhals.eu/xlayer-power-saver-65w-weiss-219703-a2898923.html)
- [67W (3.25A@20V) via USB-A (no USB-C)](https://geizhals.eu/xiaomi-67w-usb-travel-charger-weiss-mdy-12-eu-a2907863.html)
- [80W (7.3A@11V) via USB-A (30W via USB-C)](https://geizhals.eu/oneplus-supervooc-80w-car-charger-schwarz-5411100003-a2953140.html)